Is Conditional formatting based on "today" will be highlighted tomorrow?
I have just used conditional formatting to highlight a cell if it contains a date equals to Today. I want to know when tomorrow comes and it becomes "Today", will it be highlighted?


No, tomorrow isn’t today. The excel spreadsheet would have to likely be recalculated if you are actively looking at the spreadsheet between 2359 and 0001.

Why not wait until tomorrow and see what happens?

It also depends if the cell contains a fixed date, or if the date is based on a formula (e.g., yesterday+1).
